# Using different resolution presets with AVFoundation

Tags: iphone, ios, avfoundation, avcapturesession

I'm trying to use AVFoundation to have three recording modes: Audio, Video and Photo. Audio and Video work just fine, but the problem is, if I set the session preset to AVCaptureSessionPreset352x288, the still pictures are also saved at that resolution. If I change my session preset to AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto, then the photos look great but the video stops working because that isn't a supported preset for video. I've tried creating multiple sessions, reassigning the session preset, etc. but nothing seems to work. Anyone have a way to make this work with the video at a low resolution and still images at full resolution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

before taking the picture set the property for a new session preset

```
// captureSession is your capture session object
[captureSession beginConfiguration];
captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh;
[captureSession commitConfiguration];
```

then call your capture image handler

```
captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection: completionHandler:
```

then change back to low res (= prevPreset)

```
[captureSession beginConfiguration];
captureSession.sessionPreset = prevPreset;
[captureSession commitConfiguration];
```

Comment: Is this method appropriate to acquire a full-resolution image (I mean a 5MP or 8MP image according to device photo-capture resolution) or it is just an improvement to acquire an image at the higher resolution supported by video-capture?
If the answer is yes, what is the value to use at .sessionPreset for a photo-capture resolution?
Do the video-preview freeze while capturing the (high-res) photo?